# Is there anything equivalent of projection/binding of functions in R?

Tags: r

In KDB/Q, let say you have a function f(x,y,z). Let say that you know that you are always going to pass the same x to this function f. Then a new function can be defined g <- f(x;;). Now, one can use g as any other function. For instance, f = x+y+z. x =2. Then g(3,4)= 2+3+4. g(5,6) = 2+5+6. Is there anything equivalent of that in R? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called currying:

```
library(functional)
f <- function(x, y, z) x + y + z
g <- Curry(f, x = 2)
g(5, 6) # 13
```

Comment: cool! So is there any way, I can curry a function f(x,y) x+y g=f(2;) and apply this one-dimensional function on a list? For instance, in KDB/Q, we would get g@/: (1;2;3;4;5) = (3;4;5;6;7)

Comment: In this case `g` is a vectorized function since `+` is so `g(1:5)` would work or more generally `sapply(1:5, g)` .  Also note that in terms of `f` that in this particular case `f(2, 1:5)` works and `more generally sapply(1:5, f, x = 2)` work.